# Как сделать счётчик на количество вызванных ajax запросов?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть несколько форм на которые можно ответить Одобрен/Отклонён. После нажатия на Одобрен/Отклонён вызывается AJAX. Хотелось бы чтобы при удачном вызове AJAX к span добавлялось +1, +2 и тд. Как это правильнее сделать?

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var formaElement = $(".container");
  var counter = 0;
  formaElement.find("form[id*='zaya']").each(function() {
    var stringsp = 'zaya';
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("form[id*='zaya']")[counter];
    var idElement = element.id;
    var need = idElement.split(stringsp);
    var need = need[1];
    $("#odoZaSe"+need).click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var newDivOtk = document.getElementById("creaDivOtk"+need);
      newDivOtk.remove();
      var odob = "True";
      sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'zaya'+need, 'zayavki.php', odob);
      var forRemo = "zaya"+need";
      removeForm(forRemo);//Удаляем отправленную форму
        return false;
    });
    counter++;
  });
});
function otkZa(idza, coun){
  var desc = document.createElement("div");
  desc.className = "form-group";
  desc.id = "creaDivOtk"+coun;
  desc.innerHTML = "<label>Причина отказа:</label>"+
  "<input name=\"desc\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Причина\">"+
  "<input class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"text\" name = \"otkZaSe"+idza+"\" id=\"otkZaSe"+coun+"\" readonly value=\"Отклонить\">";
  var placeDiv = document.getElementById("otkZa"+coun);
  var parent = placeDiv.parentNode;
  parent.insertBefore(desc, placeDiv);
  placeDiv.remove();
  var rem = document.getElementById("odoZaSe"+coun);
  rem.remove();
  var forRemo = document.getElementById("id ='zaya"+coun+"']");
  $("#otkZaSe"+coun).click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var odob = "False";
      sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'zaya'+coun, 'zayavki.php', odob);
      removeForm(forRemo);//Удаляем отправленную форму
        return false;
    });
}
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, reg_form, url, odob) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url,
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+reg_form).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          result = $.parseJSON(response);
          if(result.good == "True"){
            var message = document.getElementById('result_form');
            message.innerHTML += "<p style='color: red;'>Операция произведена</p>";
            message.scrollIntoView();
            if(odob == "True"){
              var span = document.getElementById('prinato');
              var text = document.getElementById('prinato').textContent;
              span.innerHTML = text+"<p style='color: red;'>+ "+number+"</p>";
              //Вот здесь должно добавляться +1, +2 и тд.
            }else if (odob == "False") {
              var span = document.getElementById('nePrinato');
              var text = document.getElementById('nePrinato').textContent;
              span.innerHTML = text+"<p style='color: red;'>+ "+number+"</p>";
              //Вот здесь должно добавляться +1, +2 и тд.
            }
          }
        },
        error: function(response) { 
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

html $counterZaya - Просто счётчик, $idZaya - id заявки:

```
<p>
<!--Тут из БД берётся кол-во заявок до запросов-->
Принятые заявки: <span id = 'prinato' class = ''>$countPrin</span>
Не принятые заявки: <span id = 'nePrinato' class = ''>$countNePrin</span>
</p>
<div id="result_form"></div>
<div class="container">
  <!--Тут в цикле выводятся формы-->
  <form id=\"zaya$counterZaya\" class=\"buttons\">
    <input name="odoZaSe$idZaya" id = "odoZaSe$counterZaya" type="text" class="btn btn-primary" value="Одобрить" readonly>
    <button onclick="otkZa($idZaya, $counterZaya);" id="otkZa$counterZaya">Отклонить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, самое простое, которое не мониторит количество отправленных запросов. Поскольку отправка запроса вынесена в функцию, то в неё можно передать условный счётчик, который вначале равен 0, а потом при удачном вызове суммируется. 
js:

```
var numberAj = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var formaElement = $(".container");
  var counter = 0;
  formaElement.find("form[id*='zaya']").each(function() {
    var stringsp = 'zaya';
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("form[id*='zaya']")[counter];
    var idElement = element.id;
    var need = idElement.split(stringsp);
    var need = need[1];
    $("#odoZaSe"+need).click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var newDivOtk = document.getElementById("creaDivOtk"+need);
      newDivOtk.remove();
      var odob = "True";
      sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'zaya'+need, 'zayavki.php', odob, numberAj);
      var forRemo = "zaya"+need";
      removeForm(forRemo);//Удаляем отправленную форму
        return false;
    });
    counter++;
  });
});
function otkZa(idza, coun){
  var desc = document.createElement("div");
  desc.className = "form-group";
  desc.id = "creaDivOtk"+coun;
  desc.innerHTML = "<label>Причина отказа:</label>"+
  "<input name=\"desc\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Причина\">"+
  "<input class=\"btn btn-primary\" type=\"text\" name = \"otkZaSe"+idza+"\" id=\"otkZaSe"+coun+"\" readonly value=\"Отклонить\">";
  var placeDiv = document.getElementById("otkZa"+coun);
  var parent = placeDiv.parentNode;
  parent.insertBefore(desc, placeDiv);
  placeDiv.remove();
  var rem = document.getElementById("odoZaSe"+coun);
  rem.remove();
  var forRemo = document.getElementById("id ='zaya"+coun+"']");
  $("#otkZaSe"+coun).click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();
      var odob = "False";
      sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'zaya'+coun, 'zayavki.php', odob, numberAj);
      removeForm(forRemo);//Удаляем отправленную форму
        return false;
    });
}
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, reg_form, url, odob, number) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url,
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+reg_form).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
          result = $.parseJSON(response);
          if(result.good == "True"){
            var message = document.getElementById('result_form');
            message.innerHTML += "<p style='color: red;'>Операция произведена</p>";
            message.scrollIntoView();
            if(odob == "True"){
              number++;
              numberAj++;
              var span = document.getElementById('prinato');
              var text = document.getElementById('prinato').textContent;
              span.innerHTML = text+"<p style='color: red;'>+ "+number+"</p>";
            }else if (odob == "False") {
              number++;
              numberAj++;
              var span = document.getElementById('nePrinato');
              var text = document.getElementById('nePrinato').textContent;
              span.innerHTML = text+"<p style='color: red;'>+ "+number+"</p>";
            }
          }
        },
        error: function(response) { 
            $('#result_form').html('Ошибка. Данные не отправлены.');
        }
    });
}
```

html без изменений.
Если это можно как-то улучшить, то буду признателен.